# Create a line, like Xcode, to connect two objects in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, swift2

I'm trying an app different from normal. The app connects two objects, like two images. If the images are identical, they can be linked.

What I am trying to create this app is the ligament between the two objects. Something like this:

[image]

My question: **How create a line, like Xcode, to connect two objects?**

And after the connection is made, the line disappears.

Comment: Are you trying to build a game? If yes, this can be done using Shape Nodes in spritekit. If its not a game, we can do this using Quartz 2d, where you add a line and then remove it after the connection is made. Tell us what the intent is and we could provide some solution.

Comment: I trying build an app. You could post an example using Quartz 2D in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use CGAffineTransform, with UIView.animateWithDuration().

Check Apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/index.html

Then, remove or hide the IBOutlet to obtain the disappear effect, also with animation, of course.